# A measure of connectedness in graph theory

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

From Wikipedia:

> A **complete graph** is a simple undirected graph in which *every pair of distinct vertices is connected by a unique edge*.

[image: Complete graph]

> A **tree** is an undirected graph in which any two vertices are connected by *exactly one path*.

[image: Tree]

To me, these two types of graphs seem like some kind of opposites in terms of connectivity. I have been searching online for a graph property that reflects this difference, like [Wiener index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_index), [circuit rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_rank), [strength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strength_of_a_graph), etc.

I couldn't find a property that measures the thing I desire: something like an averaged number that defines a node's connectivity to more than 1 node. A normalized value that should be minimum for a tree e.g. ~0 and maximum for a complete graph e.g. ~1.

Does such a measure exist in literature?

Comment: Check out [average clustering](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.cluster.average_clustering.html) it's a measure of how connected a graph is. Another useful concept is [density](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.density.html#networkx.classes.function.density)

Comment: Use the number of spanning trees divided by $n^{n-2}$?

Comment: If we require the graphs be connected, a graph of $n$  vertices has between $n-1$ and $\binom{n}{2}$ edges. These endpoints are necessarily trees and complete graphs respectively. Counting the edges could thus provide a very simple measure.

Comment: Well but there are a lot of measures of connectedness though that have been the focus of research. There are plenty of papers in the literature that study the bisection width, and $\frac{|E(S,|\bar{S})|}{\min\{|S|,|\bar{S}| \}}$, as well as more basic $k$-connectedness

Comment: There is even a whole stream of many many papers devoted to the construction of *expander graphs*, which are sparse graphs that are highly connected [if you want to find a balanced cut of an expander $G$ you need to cut a large fraction of the edges and/or vertices].

Answer (score 2):

Some relevant metrics are described [here](http://www.math.louisville.edu/Cumberland/slides/19%20-%20O.pdf). First, there is the connectivity, which describes the number of vertices you need to remove to make the graph disconnected. In the case of a tree with 3 or more vertices, this is 1. In the case of a complete graph, it is V. And in a disconnected graph it's 0, so it's easy to normalize. A similar property holds if you replace the number of vertices to remove with the number of edges to remove.

A metric which is a bit more of a global property is the [average connectivity](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X01001807), given by computing the minimum number of edges between any two vertices $\kappa(u, v)$ that you need to remove to cause the graph to be disconnected and averages over all pairs: $$\frac{\sum_{u\neq v\in V}\kappa(u,v)}{\binom{|V|}{2}}.$$
The first source also defines an analogous vertex connectivity, though I don't understand their definition for vertex connectivity when $u$ and $v$ are adjacent.

Another idea I think could be interesting, but I don't know that anyone has ever really researched is the expected number of edges/vertices that need to be removed to disconnect the graph, if you choose randomly.